# sum(vector) is 1 but sum(vector)==1 is false

Tags: r

I have a super weird issue. When I try `sum(c(.7, .2, .1))`, I get the correct result of 1. However, when I try `sum(c(.7, .2, .1))==1`, I get the result `FALSE`. Similarly for `sum(c(.69, .2, .11))==1` (also FALSE), but not for `sum(c(.65, .2, .15))==1` (`TRUE`).

I doubt this error can be reproduced, so probably is specific to my machine? I have R version 4.3.1 on a macOS Ventura 13.5.2. I get the same error both in RStudio's console and using R via terminal.

Comment: any chance this is a floating point issue ? What is the absolute value of the difference ?

Comment: It is indeed a floating point issue: if you run `format(sum(c(.7, .2, .1)), nsmall = 20)` to see 20 decimal places for the answer, R reveals that the number is not exactly 1, but 0.999...

Comment: Just to add that you are right in saying that the error is machine dependent, on my Windows 11 all test cases  return `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a related question. I guess the workaround then is with `all.equal(sum(c(0.7, 0.2, 0.1)), 1)`.